Rewrites few pages to separate nextJS application
I have two nextjs application (App1 and App2). I want to render few pages of the same path from App1 and few pages from App2.
Below is the next.config.mjs file from App1
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/pd/equipment/printers-and-copiers',
        destination: '/pd/equipment/printers-and-copiers',
      },
      {
        source: "/pd/equipment/scanner",
        destination: "/pd/equipment/scanner"
      },
      {
        source: "/pd/supplies",
        destination: "/pd/supplies"
      },
      {
        source: "/pd/:slug*",
        destination: "https://www.app2.com/en/products/pd/:slug*"
      }
    ]
  },

First three links are working fine as expected but for the fourth link which will be rewriting the /pd/:slug* to app2 is not working as expected.
When visiting /pd/:slug* on app1 content from app2 is loaded but /_next/, /Assets/, /favicon.ico are giving 404 not found error in browser network tab. When app2 content is loading .css files from /_next/ it's searching in app1 instead of app2.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)
